# What does mean "to crack upon" in English?

Tags: phrase-meaning, word-meaning, phrase-usage

Is this phrase correct?

"This political movement was actively cracked upon by the secret services"

Comment: I bet it's 'cracked **open**'. Did you hear this somewhere, YouTube, maybe?

Comment: Oh boy, I just got it: it is a passive form in spoken English but a word is missing: This political movement was actively cracked **down** on or upon by the secret services.

Comment: As an American who watches British TV, the phrase strikes me as sounding correct.  Does not mean that it is correct.  But, I find that in some London British slang, "crack" is used very differently than might be expected in American English.  I would translate that as "actively investigated, pursued or engaged", but just my interpretation.  I often rewind scenes -- with captions -- in an effort to translate the British slang.  Part of the entertainment,

Answer (score 1):

No, that sentence doesn't really make sense.

If it were "This political movement was actively cracked down on by the secret services" or "This political movement was actively spied upon by the secret services" it would be fine but "cracked upon" strikes me as very odd (AME speaker).

Comment: Just "cracked down" is wrong?

Comment: @Anixx: If you are asking if "This political movement was actively cracked down by the secret services" I would have to say that is not a meaningful statement.

Comment: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/crack-down